# How to enable the ability to change the size of an image on Mosaico template or when using a Mosaico template to design an email

Tags: civimail, mosaico

I would need that the editing options of an image is available either on the **Mosaico** templates or when designing an email from a Mosaico template.
Specifically, the option to **change the size of the image**.

I have installed the ***Mosaico Extras*** extension to be able to configure on the *Mosaico Toolbar Settings* and I have added the tool set:

*| editimage imageoptions |*

but haven't achieved anything.

Any help on that, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to follow the question, so I'll state my understanding, using screenshots.

You would like to put an image into a Mosaico image placeholder that doesn't match the resolution of the placeholder.  For example, in the image below, you want to put an image that is not 285x170 in the first image spot.

This isn't really possible, because email clients all render emails differently.  Mosaico blocks are pre-written to ensure the template comes through the same on everyone's client.  They must also resize correctly on mobile devices.

However, most blocks in the `versafix-1` template have alternate image sizes.  For instance, both blocks in the image below are the same, but you can see on the left I set *Image Size* to **Small** on the second block.

I recommend changing the *Image Size* settings if you haven't already.  In all likelihood, there is one that is close enough to what you need.

If none of those work at all, and you want to get a bit technical, you can [create a new base template and modify your blocks](https://artfulrobot.uk/blog/adding-custom-block-mosaico-email-editor-civicrm).

[image]